# Can I use supabase and render to host strapi app

Tags: database, deployment, hosting, render, strapi

I'm working on a hobby project using strapi as backend and nextjs as front end. I wanted to deploy strapi somewhere. I have tried with heroku and render and both are fantastic but not free. So I was doing some research on supabase for database and netlify for webservice. When I tried connecting the database(that created on supabase), I kept encountering SSL error. It could be unrelated but before digging further I wanted to confirm if its possible to do so. Can someone share some insight?

If its possible, can someone share the configurations and how to do it? Thanks in advance.

This was the error that I was getting.

```
Sep 14 10:41:05 PM  $ strapi start
Sep 14 10:41:36 PM  [2023-09-14 17:11:36.869] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
Sep 14 10:41:36 PM  [2023-09-14 17:11:36.872] error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Sep 14 10:41:36 PM  Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Sep 14 10:41:36 PM      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1539:34)
Sep 14 10:41:36 PM      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
Sep 14 10:41:36 PM      at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
Sep 14 10:41:36 PM      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:953:8)
Sep 14 10:41:36 PM      at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:734:12)
Sep 14 10:41:37 PM  error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

https://supabase.com/

https://strapi.io/

https://render.com/

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable answers. I have created a comprehensive guide on how to deploy strapi DB on supabase. Find it here - https://youtu.be/frjVQ66tQ5Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that the actual issue was with `DATABASE_SSL=false` Earlier I was using `DATABASE_SSL=true`. I was able to successfully deploy strap webservice on render using the database created in supabase. All you have to do is update the env variables from supabase to render. Please make sure `pg` is installed on strapi. It works like charm!

Answer (score 2):

After looking into this, currently Strapi does not support supabase. If you are looking for a free database, I have found https://www.elephantsql.com/ that allows you to spin up a PostgressDB using there free tear.

I haven't tested it yet, but will give it a try this weekend.

[Update]

I was able to spin up and use ElephantSQL free tear in my project.

Here is my `database.js` file with in strapis `config` folder.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = ({ env }) => {
  const client = env('DATABASE_CLIENT');

  const connections = {
    postgres: {
      connection: {
        connectionString: env('DATABASE_URL'),
        ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false) && {
          rejectUnauthorized: env.bool(
            'DATABASE_SSL_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED',
            true
          ),
        },
        schema: env('DATABASE_SCHEMA', 'public'),
      },
      pool: { min: env.int('DATABASE_POOL_MIN'), max: env.int('DATABASE_POOL_MAX') },
    },
  };
```

Note: when using the free tear, you will need to limit connection to 5.

Here is my database env variables within the .env file.

```
DATABASE_CLIENT=postgres
DATABASE_URL=add_your_url_here
DATABASE_SSL=false
DATABASE_SSL_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=false
DATABASE_SHEMA=public
DATABASE_POOL_MIN=2
DATABASE_POOL_MAX=5
JWT_SECRET=HRsqM7AcFvAa/cctdsqNUQ==
```

Here is the link to the demo project on GitHub.
https://github.com/PaulBratslavsky/strapi-elephand-db-free-tear-test

So you can now deploy your Strapi App to Render, Host your db on Elephant SQL, and also have a way to store your media.  Using service like Cloudinary.

Hope this help.

I think I am going to make a tutorial an how to deploy your Strapi app for free.

Will use
Render
Cloudinary
ElephantSQL

All though for production app, I would probably pay for a service like Strapi Cloud.

Comment: Hi @Paul, Thanks for digging in to it. Supabase do support strapi. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got Strapi to be deployed on Render and Supabase.

When using the free tear your app will perform super slow on initial load. But that is expected with free tear.

I have both my database and images handled by Supabase.  Wanted to post for anyone interested.

And Render hosting the app.

here is the reference project on github https://github.com/paulnotfromstrapi/strapi-base

Here are my dependencies.

```
   "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.13.6",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.13.6",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.13.6",
    "better-sqlite3": "8.6.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "strapi-provider-upload-supabase": "^1.0.0"
```

note: the "strapi-provider-upload-supabase" plugin is not an official plugin by Strapi.  It is update for v4 but only support node 16 I believe.

https://github.com/crubier/strapi-provider-upload-supabase

Here is my plugins.js file where I set up this provider.

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: "strapi-provider-upload-supabase",
      providerOptions: {
        apiUrl: env("SUPABASE_API_URL"),
        apiKey: env("SUPABASE_API_KEY"),
        bucket: env("SUPABASE_BUCKET"),
        directory: env("SUPABASE_DIRECTORY"),
        options: {},
      },
      actionOptions: {
        upload: {},
        uploadStream: {},
        delete: {},
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Here is my database.js file

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => {
  const client = env("DATABASE_CLIENT");

  const connections = {
    postgres: {
      connection: {
        connectionString: env("DATABASE_URL"),

        ssl: env.bool("DATABASE_SSL", false) && {
          rejectUnauthorized: env.bool(
            "DATABASE_SSL_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED",

            true
          ),
        },

        schema: env("DATABASE_SCHEMA", "public"),
      },

      pool: {
        min: env.int("DATABASE_POOL_MIN"),
        max: env.int("DATABASE_POOL_MAX"),
      },
    },
  };

  return {
    connection: {
      client,

      ...connections[client],

      acquireConnectionTimeout: env.int("DATABASE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT", 60000),
    },
  };
};
```

[image]

I like this stack as an option when developing an app for fun.  And wanting to have something started without using a credit card.

But I dont think it makes sense for production.

Lol. Just my opinion.

I like to host my project and db (especially when it is Postgres ) in the same place.

Rather then database as a service where you are connected over the public internet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use supabase as a database and an external service to host strapi.

I have a test project in which I have strapi at https://render.com (free) and I have the database in supabase

your `.env` file has to have this for the database

```
# Supabase DB
DATABASE_HOST=""
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_NAME=""
DATABASE_USERNAME=""
DATABASE_PASSWORD=""
DATABASE_SCHEMA=""
DATABASE_SSL=false
```

And it is important to have the `DATABASE_CLIENT` as postgres

```
DATABASE_CLIENT=postgres
```

In render.com it is important that you configure everything in your `.env`

And if you need to store images, you can also use supabase, I followed these steps

https://forum.strapi.io/t/using-supabase-for-the-postgres-database/16762

https://github.com/crubier/strapi-provider-upload-supabase

Answer (score 0):

[Update 3] I was able to test deploying Strapi for free using Render, ElephantSQL and Cloudinary using all their free tears. Here is the project link.  I used render.yaml file to configure the deploy.  You can use the render bluepring option to deploy this project. https://github.com/PaulBratslavsky/strapi-free-deploy-render-elephant-cloudinary

Answer (score 0):

I tested all the functionality in Supabase it and it works..  I know you can setup additional policies on supabase side of things.  I wonder how that would integrate with Strapi.

Strapi is compatible with Strapi but is not supported by Strapi.

See here for more https://support.strapi.io/support/solutions/articles/67000718580-how-do-i-use-a-custom-database-with-strapi-cloud-

Comment: Its working as expected so far. But initial loading time is ridiculous. Assuming its free tier issues. But rest looks good.

Comment: I cannot understand your middle paragraph at all. what does it mean?